# MySQL Datediff - what is the issue?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datediff

I have the following problem. My database looks like this:

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLPyS.png)

I want to fetch all data from this database which is older than 2 days and the     `status = "Betreiber informiert"` or `status = "Betreiber informiert (manuell)"`

I have created a query but it is not working. Can someone help me?

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM meldungen 
WHERE status = 'Betreiber informiert' 
   OR status = 'Betreiber informiert(manuell)' 
  AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Meldungszeitpunkt) > 172800
```

If I use this query, it looks like this:

[Result with my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfkx0.png)

You can see my query selects all rows which have `status='Betreiber informiert'` or `'Betreiber informiert(manuell)'` but the days are not considered.

Can someone help me?

Comment: When you mix AND/OR, the query gets confused. It's best to use parenthesis to block off the specific logic.

Comment: What is `172800` supposed to represent? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Calculate Days ins seconds

Comment: please don't use a screenshot like that, dump the create table result of  `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` instead

Answer (score 2):

Huh?  What is 172800?

Try this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM meldungen m
WHERE m.status IN ('Betreiber informiert', 'Betreiber informiert(manuell)') AND
      m.Meldungszeitpunkt < NOW() - interval 2 day;
```

Note that this also simplifies the logic to use `IN` -- because I am guessing that you want the date condition applied to both statuses.  If you really only want the date condition applied to the second one, then you would use:

```
WHERE m.status = 'Betreiber informiert' OR
      (m.status = 'Betreiber informiert(manuell)') AND
       m.Meldungszeitpunkt < NOW() - interval 2 day
      )
```

That interpretation seems much less likely to me (although it is what your query does).

You might want `curdate()` rather than `now()`, unless you want to take the time into account.

Comment: *"Huh? What is 172800?

Try this:"* - I'd expect an answer like that from a very low rep member. *lol*

Comment: @user2864740 . . . That is because the obvious change would be on the date comparisons.  The `IN` is just a simplification.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know that. But look at it this way. What would you have done had that answer came from a new member or low rep member? I've seen answers like that before where they received a lot of downvotes. Be honest now.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner . . . I honestly don't know what a `datediff()` value of `172800` has to do with 2 days.  Perhaps the OP can provide enlightenment, although that is not necessary to get the right logic for the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `172800` is the number of _seconds_ in two days (q.v. my answer).  Your answer is the way to go here, almost for certain.  I gave an answer just to clarify this one point.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Writing a good answer includes being able to explain/justify changes and recommendations. It was never claimed the answer itself was incorrect nor that the answer’s author is “inexperienced”, merely that the answer was wanting initially. As the answer has been updated, so has at least one initial vote.

Answer (score 2):

`172800` is the numbers of *seconds* in two full days.  If you really want to do it this way, then you should be using `TIMESTAMPDIFF`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM meldungen m
WHERE
    m.status IN ('Betreiber informiert', 'Betreiber informiert(manuell)') AND
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, Meldungszeitpunkt, NOW()) > 172800;
```

Note that I use `WHERE IN` to avoid the problem of order of operation between your `OR`s and `AND`s.  `AND` has highest precedence than `OR`, so your original `WHERE` clause was actually evaluating as this:

```
WHERE
    status = 'Betreiber informiert' OR
    (status = 'Betreiber informiert(manuell)' AND
     DATEDIFF(NOW(), Meldungszeitpunkt) > 172800)
```

Comment: @user2864740 This is the intended logic AFAIK.  If you have reason to believe otherwise, then show some evidence for that.

Comment: The update covers the “IN” switch- my only issue was the lack of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to change your code to the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM meldungen 
WHERE status = 'Betreiber informiert' 
  AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Meldungszeitpunkt) > 172800 
   OR status = 'Betreiber informiert(manuell)' 
  AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Meldungszeitpunkt) > 172800
```

You have to write the `AND` Task for every `OR`

With your old code it is just searching for "Betreiber informiert" from every timestamp and for "Betreiber informiert (manuell)" that is older than two days.

Comment: While this changes the logic (which may or may not be the OPs issue), “(A and C) or (B and C)” can be more simply written as “(A or B) and C” to avoid repetition.

Comment: Yes, you can do that too, but I like to structure it so I can change everything individually